# Magento 2 : Problem while adding custom button order view page?

Tags: magento2, sales-order

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context">
        <plugin name="add_custom_button_sales_veiw" type="MyModule\RK\Plugin\Widget\Context" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Context.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\RK\Plugin\Widget;

class Context
{
    public function afterGetButtonList(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $subject,
         $buttonList
    )
    {
        if($subject->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){
            $buttonList->add(
                'custom_button',
                [
                    'label' => 'test',
                    'onclick' => "setLocation('window.location.href')",
                    'class' => 'ship'
                ]
            );
        }

        return $buttonList;
    }
}
```

Review button is not displaying on order view page what i am doing wrong ??

Comment: Whats your di.xml location?

Comment: vendor/modulename/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your di.xml [Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml]:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context">
        <plugin name="add_custom_button_sales_veiw" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Widget\Context" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create plugin [Vendor/Module/Plugin/Widget/Context.php]

```
namespace Vedor\Module\Plugin\Widget;


class Context
{
    public function afterGetButtonList(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $subject,
        $buttonList
    )
    {
        if($subject->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){
            $buttonList->add(
                'custom_button',
                [
                    'label' => __('Custom Button'),
                    'onclick' => "setLocation('window.location.href')",
                    'class' => 'ship'
                ]
            );
        }

        return $buttonList;
    }
}
```

Clear cache.

Read here [for more detail](https://ranasohel.me/2015/11/23/how-to-add-custom-button-in-admin-order-detail-page-in-magento-2/)

Comment: its not working yet ? I think function is not calling because i try to print hello in this function but nothing is printing. May be problem in my di.xml. Please suggest me

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: yes i am doing exactly same but not working ...

Comment: Which version you have tried? Make sure your module active.

Comment: 2.1.0  and my module is active

Comment: Clear cache, It's working fine for M2.1

Comment: Sorry @sohel but it's not working for me. I have updated my question plz check and let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: i am trying this in existing module. Should i try with a new module ?

Comment: It should work existing and new module too. Better create a new one and try

Comment: yes after creating new one its working ... Thank you @Sohel for your guidence.